# Combining a dynamic total by state in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am using a US shootings database where the event is specified by 3 columns, state event occured, date, total casualties. I want to make a dashboard in Tableau that has dynamic sum and sorting where if the year column was a page that I could click through, the graphic would reflect the top ten states of sum(casualties) of that specified range. So my data ranges from 1924-2022, and if I started the page at 1980, it would graph the top 10 states with the sum of totals between 1924-1980. The next page could potentially be a different top 10 of states and would reflect the current top 10 states as the sum(casualties) from 1924-1981.

I hope this makes sense. I apologize if it does not as I am just starting out. I did attempt to sort the data in python by making a column for each year, and you could move horizontally along a state to see it's totals change as each year goes by. Would it be best to add these year columns as a group and sort by top 10 and year that way?

Edit:
[Attempting to click through the year filter and dynamically sort the graph by top 10 states with total shootings from 1924-current year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLHRq.jpg)

Comment: Please share your work in Tableau public, so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SQL to query the database? If so, you can insert a date parameter in the query that replaces the use of pages to calculate the sum based on the earliest datapoint to the year you have selected and then just click show parameter. When you create the parameter make sure you set step size to one year and switch the parameter to slider. You can also create a state parameter that is based off that column of data and then use it to filter the data in SQL. However, you may need to use a calculated field or SQL case statements if you want to change the granularity from all the states to one selected state.
I hope this helps you. If you need more clarification, please comment and I will try to provide an example.